# AWS NATゲートウェイとEIP に関する Allocation IDとassociation ID の存在理由

Tags: aws, network, vpc

AWSのネットワークリソースに関して質問させてください。

**NATゲートウェイとEIPの関係を示すものとして、Allocation IDとAssociation IDの二つがあるようですが、なぜ2つあるのでしょうか？**

最近AWSリソースの整理をしていたのですが、その際浮いているEIPを追っていたら、最終的にNATゲートウェイに行きつきました。

EIP
↓  Association ID
NAT が所有する ENI
↓  Attachment ID
NAT Gateway

追っていく中で上記のような関係を見たのですが、ENIを通してNATとEIPをつなぐAssociation ID以外にも、NATとEIPを直接つないでいるように見えるAllocation IDがありました。

NATを作るときには自動的にENIも生成されるようですし、どうにも2つ別々にある理由がわかりません。

何か勘違いをしておりますでしょうか？
それともAWSの進化の過程で残された痕跡なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Allocation IDはElastic IPアドレス (EIP) のIDです。Association IDは、EIPとリソース（この場合はNAT Gateway）とのリレーションのIDです。

EIPを作成するとAllocation IDが払い出されます。作成したEIPをリソースに関連付けると、Association IDが払い出されます。